# Only return unique element in python

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I have run into a problem with my Python code.
I am creating a movie filter after i scraped IMDB for certain movies.
However, the problem is that movies with multiple genres will show up identically in my movie_filter.
So my code is following:

```
    def create_movies_drop_down(self):
        movies = []

        if "genres" in self.mappingQuery:
            mapping = [row for row in dataLakeDB["nordisk-film-movie-mapping"].find(dict(genres = self.mappingQuery["genres"]))]
        else:
            mapping = [row for row in dataLakeDB["nordisk-film-movie-mapping"].find()]
        for row in mapping:
            if row["title"] not in movies:
                movies.append(dict(movie = row["title"][0].upper()+row["title"][1:],
                                    imdbPageID = row["imdbPageID"]))
        return movies
```

Now i.e because the movie "DRUK" has the genres "Comende and drama" it will show up 2 times with the same title and imdb page ID.
I have tried with multiple arguments, but can't seem to solve the specific reason why this happens.
Can anyone help here?

Edit: The mapping for 1 movie is like this:
[{'_id': '6028139039cba4ae2722f8d9', 'castList': '[Rosa Salazar, Christoph Waltz, Jennifer Connelly, Mahershala Ali, Ed Skrein]', 'clientID': 'FILM', 'dcmCampaignID': [''], 'director': 'Robert Rodriguez', 'dv360InsertionOrderID': ['7675053', '7675055', '7675065', '768
3006', '7863461'], 'genres': ['action', 'adventure', 'sci-fi'], 'imdbPageID': '0437086', 'imdbPageURL': 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0437086', 'imdbRating': '7.3', 'marathonCountryID': 'PMDK', 'posterURL': 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTQzYWYwYjctY2JhZS00
NTYzLTllM2UtZWY5ZTk0NmYwYzIyXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMzgxODM4NjM@.*V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL*.jpg', 'title': 'alita: battle angel\xa0(2019)'}

Comment: Use `set` like `set(['a', 'b', 'a'])` will give `{'a', 'b'}`

Comment: can you provide us with some example data from `self.mappingQuery` and `dataLakeDB`? We need to understand what we're dealing with.

Comment: Yes sorry about that, I've edited it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since movies is a list of dictionaries (which are unhashable), converting it to a set to get rid of duplicates will not work.  Instead you have to iterate and append each movie to the movies list on the condition that it does not already exist there. You have already tried to do this with the if statement inside the for loop.  The problem is that your if statement is always True because your are checking just for a Title and not for the whole dictionary object.  You can fix it like this:

```
def create_movies_drop_down(self):
    movies = []
    if "genres" in self.mappingQuery:
        mapping = [row for row in
                   dataLakeDB["nordisk-film-movie-mapping"].find(dict(genres=self.mappingQuery["genres"]))]
    else:
        mapping = [row for row in dataLakeDB["nordisk-film-movie-mapping"].find()]
    for row in mapping:
        movie_dic = dict(movie=row["title"][0].upper() + row["title"][1:],
                               imdbPageID=row["imdbPageID"])
        if movie_dic not in movies:
            movies.append(movie_dic)
    return movies
```

Comment: Hey, I see how this should work slight problem is that movies is like this [{'movie': 'Alita: battle angel\xa0(2019)', 'imdbPageID': '0437086'}, so if i use set I get the error: unhashable type "dict".

Comment: @SebastianStraussHansenn See my new answer above.